# Polymorphism object creation - diamond inheritance hierarchy

Tags: oop, diamond-problem

Language : C/C++
Problem : Taking the common example, where

- **A** is the parent class.
- **B** and **C** both inherited from class **A**.
- **D** is inherited from both **B** and **C**

and we want to access **A**'s function through an object of **D**

Note: it's virtual inheritance! So we know there will be only one object of **A**.

The question is : Whose object will be first created **B**'s or **C**'s ?

Keeping the hierarchy in mind

```
   A
 /   \
B     C
 \   /
   D
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is *no guarantee* in OO itself regarding this.

If you're talking specific implementations or languages (but the question does not) there may be guarantees regarding this.

Comment: @AliShahzeb In C++ it depends on the order you're listing the classes you're inheriting, for example, `class D : public B, public C` would construct B before C.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this problem is sometimes also apostrophed as *diamond of death*.

Unfortunately, **your question cannot be answered: it is based on the current language you are programming in.**

For instance, in Scala (where multiple inheritance is allowed for traits), there is a quite rigirous rule for instantiation along the [linearization algorithm](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ScalaObjectSystem.html#Linearization), there you can find the proper details.

I suppose you're playing with C++. If that's right, take a look on the proper section of the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mi-vi-ctor-order.html) ([the problem is also mentioned there](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mi-diamond.html)).

Comment: thnx for answering :) i owe you big one :)

Comment: No prob, but you could add the label of the language you are coding in, and also edit the question text just to make it more informative for others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking C++ and the order of instantion of the classes, then it will depend on the inheritance order in the declaration.

So, in

```
class D :  public B,public C
```

B will be instantiated first then C.

```
class D :  public C,public B
```

C will be instantiated first then B.